# How is Torricelli's law different if we change the size of the air vent?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, flow

I was wondering how does Torricelli's law vary if the opening at the top of the tank is varied.

Most calculations make it given that the tank has a completely open air vent, but how would that change if the tank was reduced in size. How could we derive a mathematical relationship between the area of the air vent opening and how long it takes for the tank to drain?

[image: Torricelli's law]

Comment: As long as the air opening is 'big enough' it does not matter. Since air is roughly 1/1000 as dense as water, how big is 'big enough'?

Comment: What about for viscous fluids like oil